# How to simulate Visual Assist feature "Move to Previous Scope" and "Move to Next Scope" in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

There is a feature in the Visual Assist extension for MS Visual Studio, called "Move to Next Scope" (and "Move to Previous Scope") that I use regularly to navigate our company's large codebase.

[VSAssist keyboard shortcuts link](https://www.wholetomato.com/learn/keyboardshortcuts) and an illustration of what I'm talking about:
[image: Visual Assist Move to Prev/Next scope keybinding in MS Visual Studio]

Sadly, I was unable to find such a feature in VSCode.

"Go to Next Folding Range" and "Go to Previous Folding Range" offer similar functionality but it is not complete, since they can't perform "Go to Parent Fold" automatically when they reach the first or the last "sub-range".

I considered using VSCode's "[Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by)" extension's feature "Move By Regular Expression" but simply moving by regex is not what I want. There is "Move By Calculation" but it doesn't seem to be it either.

Have you ever experienced the same problem? Were you able to solve it? If so, I would appreciate it greatly if you can tell me how.